# ng2-file-upload : how to prevent ----webkitboundary being sent

Tags: angular, azure, file-upload

Currently inside my angular2 project I use ng2fileupload to upload some files to azure blob storage.

For some reason the uploaded file is corrupt when received server side.
The reason the file i corrupt is because the file content is wrapped inside text:

**-----------------webKitBoundary7e133e31c05a0**
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="service_catalog3.png"
Content-Type: image/png

‰PNG  (actual png content) 
....
**-----------------------------7e133e31c05a0--**

How do I prevent that my file content is being wrapped iside this weird  webKitBoundary7e133e31c05a0 string?

Any help on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Found it. Cost me several hours :-(

You need to set **disableMultipart** to TRUE

```
var uo: FileUploaderOptions = {};
uo.disableMultipart = true;

this.uploader.setOptions(uo);
```

Hope this helps someone !!